# NSButton Alternate Title binding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

How do I bind NSButton's alternate title?

In my model object I have a boolean value, that represents what the button's title should be. For example if the user isAdmin, the button's value is Edit. If the user !isAdmin the button's title is View.

Currently I am using an NSValueTransformer, to transform the boolean value into a string. But this quickly becomes cumbersome, when I have multiple buttons with different titles.

I tried binding the button's alternate title to the aforementioned boolean value and in the buttons properties giving the button a Title and an Alternate title, but this didn't work.

Comment: What is the type of your button? Some button types don't display an alternate title.

Comment: If you are binding the button's title to a string that is a property in a class, why not subclass it for admin and set the strings differently?

Comment: @Willeke - The button is Inline button. Also tried toggle button to no avail.

Comment: @stevesliva - because I have many different buttons that have different titles based on the isAdmin status. This would mean like 10 different subclasses of NSButton, if I understand your suggestion correctly...

Comment: @ThomasHyde I meant one additional controller subclass.   Probably a view controller.   Or otherwise put the logic behind whatever class owns the strings